# Inserting Multiple Records into a custom object which has a reference to another object

Tags: apex, rest-api, custom-object, workbench, reference

I have the following REST webservice for inserting multiple records into a custom object Tickets.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MultiTicket/*')
global with sharing class MultiTicketRestController{
   global class RequestBody {
       global List<Ticket__c> tickets;
   }

    @HttpPost   
    global static List<Ticket__c> createBulk(MultiTicketRestController.RequestBody req) {
        insert req.tickets; 
        return req.tickets;
    }
}
```

The object Ticket__c has a reference to object Payment__c through a unique ID field in Payments. How can I insert into this field using a request.I am doing this through workbench.

Answer (score 2):

If that field is marked as an "External Id", you can do this. Ensure that the field `Payment__r.ExternalId__c` (or whatever the names are) is properly set and then execute an `upsert` instead of an `insert`

A quick-and-dirty sample would be as follows

Your calling function should implement the equivalent of the following APEX code

```
for (Ticket__c ticket : req.tickets) {
  ticket.Payment__c = new Payment__c();
  ticket.Payment__r.ExternalId__c = 'Your External Id Value';
}
```

Your class would look like this

```
@HttpPost   
global static List<Ticket__c> createBulk(MultiTicketRestController.RequestBody req) {
    upsert req.tickets; 
    return req.tickets;
}
```